# Calculation of points if there are 2 student with same rank in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Rank_Table

```
ID  Rank    
1   1   
2   1   
3   3   
4   3   
5   5
```

Price

```
No  Points  
1   10  
2   9   
3   8   
4   7   
5   6
```

Expected Output

```
ID  Rank    Points  
1   1       9.5     
2   1       9.5     
3   3       7.5     
4   3       7.5     
5   5       6
```

2nd rank is not present so 1st and 2nd points are sum together and distributed among the number of the student
for eg : (10+9) / 2 = 9.5

When I join the 2 table like

```
select *
from Rank_table a join
     Price b
     on a.ID = b.No
```

I am getting the output as

```
ID  Rank    No  Points  
1   1      1    10  
2   1      2    9   
3   3      3    8   
4   3      4    7   
5   5      5    6
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems to be quite a simple requirement, simply using `AVG` and an `OVER` clause.

```
CREATE TABLE [Rank] (ID int, [Rank] int)
CREATE TABLE Price ([No] int, Points int);
GO

INSERT INTO [Rank]
VALUES
(1,1),   
(2,1),   
(3,3),   
(4,3),   
(5,5);   

INSERT INTO Price
VALUES
(1,10),  
(2,9),  
(3,8),  
(4,7),  
(5,6);
GO
SELECT R.ID,
       R.[Rank],
       AVG(CONVERT(decimal(2,0),P.Points)) OVER (PARTITION BY R.[Rank]) AS Points
FROM [Rank] R
     JOIN Price P ON R.ID = P.[No];

GO
DROP TABLE [Rank];
DROP TABLE Price;
```

Answer (score 2):

You need simple `JOIN` :

```
select rn.*,
       avg(convert(decimal(10,0), p.Points)) over (partition by rn.rnk) as points
from Rank_Table rn inner join 
     Price p
     on p.id = rn.No;
```

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm.  You seem to want a non-equijoin based on the "next" rank as well as the rank in each row.  Unfortunately, SQL Server 2008 doesn't support `lead()`, but you can use `apply`:

```
select rt.id, rt.rank, avg(p.price * 1.0) as points
from rank_table rt outer apply
     (select min(rt2.rank) as next_rank
      from rank_table rt2
      where rt2.rank > rt.rank
     ) rt2 left join
     price p
     on p.no >= rt.rank >= p.no and
        (p.no < rt2.next_rank or rt2.next_rank is null)
group by rt.id, rt.rank;
```

Comment: Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 4
Incorrect syntax near 't2'.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *, 
   AA.pts AS POINTS 
FROM   rank_table R 
   INNER JOIN (SELECT rank, 
                      Sum(points) / Count(*) AS PTS 
               FROM   rank_table a 
                      JOIN price b 
                        ON a.id = b.no 
               GROUP  BY rank)AA 
           ON ( R.rank = AA.rank )
```

Answer (score 0):

You can calculate AVG at rank level and then join back to Rank_Table like in this <kbd>**[working demo](http://rextester.com/MPHX98839)**</kbd>

```
select R.*,T.points from Rank_table R
JOIN
(
select rank, points=avg(cast(points as decimal(10,2)))
from Rank_table a join
     Price b
     on a.ID = b.No
 group by rank
    )T
    on T.rank=R.rank
```